# Integrating JQuery for use with Blackberry Widgets

Tags: jquery, blackberry-widgets

At the WES 2009 event RIM announced that they were almost 100% tested with using JQuery in Widget development, does anyone know how this works?

I've tried following the demo from their site and added the following:

```
<head>
    ....
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    ....
    <a href='#' id="viewDets">View Details</a>
</body>
```

I've then added a standard jQuery click event in the other included js file:

```
$(function() {
    $('#viewDets').click(function() {
        alert('hi');
    });
});
```

but when I click on the #viewDets linke nothing is happening.  I tried using an `<input type="button" id="viewDets">` but nothing with this either.

Lastly I tried adding a manual `onclick="testJQuery()"` to a button and then had the javascript as

```
function testJQuery(){
  alert($);
}
```

which alerted the following:

```
function (E, F) {
  return new o.fn.init(E,F)
}
```

which shows that jQuery was loaded correctly?  Does this mean that currently RIM don't support using jQuery in their widgets or do they have a seperate js file or something?

Comment: What version of Blackberry OS are you using?  I know that Widgets will only work on OS 5 and greater.  The browser you are testing with may be a 4.x version of the OS and not support Javascript (at least not in the way you want).

Answer (score 0):

JQuery is unsupported on the BlackBerry browser, as it doesn't implement the entire DOM.  You may have better luck with XUI.

Answer (score 0):

[jqlite](http://code.google.com/p/jqlite/) is a BlackBerry 5.0 compatible subset of jQuery, it works pretty well.